# End array input with a newline?

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

Not sure if the title is properly worded, but what I am trying to ask is how would you signify the end of input for an array using newline. Take the following code for example. Not matter how many numbers(more or less) you type during the input for score[6], it must take 6 before you can proceed. Is there a method to change it so that an array can store 6 or 100 variables, but you can decide how many variables actually contain values. The only way I can think of doing this is to somehow incorporate '\n', so that pressing enter once creates a newline and pressing enter again signifies that you don't want to set any more values. Or is something like this not possible?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,score[6],max;
    cout<<"Enter the scores:"<<endl;
    cin>>score[0];
    max = score[0];
    for(i = 1;i<6;i++)
    {
        cin>>score[i];
        if(score[i]>max)
            max = score[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may read whole lines as text, and extract the values from that lines. An empty line entered stops the loop.

Answer (score 1):

To detect "no input was given", you will need to read the input as a input line (string), rather than using `cin >> x;` - no matter what the type is of `x`, `cin >> x;` will skip over "whitespace", such as newlines and spaces.

The trouble with reading the input as lines is that you then have to "parse" the input into numbers. You can use `std::stringstream` or similar to do this, but it's quite a bit of extra code compared to what you have now.

The typical way to solve this kind of problem, however, is to use a "sentry" value - for example, if your input is always going to be greater or equal to zero, you can use `-1` as the sentry. So you enter

```
1 2 3 4 5 -1
```

This would reduce the amount of extra code is relatively small - just check if the input is `-1`, such as

```
while(cin >> score[i] && score[i] >= 0)
{
  ... 
}
```

(This will also detect end-of-file, so you could end the input with CTRL-Z or CTRL-D as appropriate for your platform)